# Can you have a non top-level Dockerfile when invoking COPY?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Have a Dockerfile to build releases for an Elixir/Phoenix application...The tree directory structure is as follows, where the Dockerfile (which has a dependency on this [other Dockerfile](https://github.com/bitwalker/alpine-elixir/blob/master/Dockerfile)) is in the "infra" subfolder and needs access to all the files one level above "infra".

```
.
├── README.md
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   ├── js
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
├── lib
├── infra
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── deployment.yaml
```

The Dockerfile looks like:

```
# https://github.com/bitwalker/alpine-elixir
FROM bitwalker/alpine-elixir:latest

# Set exposed ports
EXPOSE 4000
ENV PORT=4000

ENV MIX_ENV=prod
ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV APP_VERSION=0.0.1
COPY ./ ${HOME}
WORKDIR ${HOME}
RUN mix deps.get
RUN mix compile
RUN MIX_ENV=${MIX_ENV} mix distillery.release
RUN echo $HOME
COPY ${HOME}/_build/${MIX_ENV}/rel/my_app/releases/${APP_VERSION}/my_app.tar.gz .
RUN tar -xzvf my_app.tar.gz

USER default

CMD ./bin/my_app foreground
```

The command "mix distillery.release" is what builds the my_app.tar.gz file in the path indicated by the COPY command.

I invoke the `docker build` as follows in the top-level directory (the parent directory of "infra"):

```
docker build -t my_app:local -f infra/Dockerfile .
```

I basically then get an error with COPY:

```
Step 13/16 : COPY ${HOME}/_build/${MIX_ENV}/rel/my_app/releases/${APP_VERSION}/my_app.tar.gz .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder246562111/opt/app/_build/prod/rel/my_app/releases/0.0.1/my_app.tar.gz: no such file or directory
```

I understand that the COPY command depends on the "build context" but I thought that by issuing the "docker build" in the parent directory of infra meant I had the appropriate context set for the COPY, but clearly that doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a way to have a Dockerfile one level below the parent directory that contains all the files needed to build an Elixir/Phoenix "release" (the my_app.tar.gz and associated files created via the command `mix distillery.release`)? What bits am I missing?

Comment: Is there an `opt/app/_build/prod/rel/my_app/releases/0.0.1` folder inside your build context? All paths are relative to the build context, not to the host path.

Comment: Is the `my_app.tar.gz` created by the `RUN mix ...` command?  You might need to `RUN cp ...` to copy files within the image tree, rather than `COPY` from the build context.

Comment: @BMitch - I'm not sure - one thing I'm confused about - is the "." in the "docker build" command mean the build context is set to the current directory where "docker build" is being run or how do I know what the "build context" is?

Comment: @DavidMaze - yes, my_app.tar.gz is created by `RUN mix ...` .. when I did `RUN cp ...` that worked, so thank you!

Comment: @nona Yes, the `.` is the current directory and is passed as the build context.